# How can I use modern kotlin functional techniques to solve this recursive loop problem?

Tags: kotlin, recursion, functional-programming

I have a kotlin problem, can you come up with a elegant way of solving it?

so effectively I have a list of objects which I want to arrange in order based on whether there is a chain.
This is the model object

```
data class Sequence(
    val id: String,
    val previousSequence: List<String>
  )
```

So the `previousSequence` tells you whether or not it is in a chain and contains an id of another sequence (or it can be empty). previousSequence is a list of strings but you can assume that  the list will only contain one entry. (Don't ask I'm inheriting somebody else poor design)

So effectively the test data below

```
  Sequence("2b", listOf("1a")),
  Sequence("1a", emptyList()),
  Sequence("3c", listOf("2b")),
  Sequence("91z", emptyList()),
  Sequence("92z", listOf("91z")),
  Sequence("NO_CHAIN", emptyList())
```

results in a list of lists as follows:

```
[
  [
   Sequence(id=1a, previousSequence=[]), 
   Sequence(id=2b, previousSequence=[1a]), 
   Sequence(id=3c, previousSequence=[2b])
  ], 
  
  [
   Sequence(id=91z, previousSequence=[]), 
   Sequence(id=92z, previousSequence=[91z])
  ]
]
```

The below code works.. using recursion. but was hoping for a more elegant solution. Can you come up with one?

```
data class Sequence(
    val id: String,
    val previousSequence: List<String>
  )

  @Test
  fun `Test chaining of sequence`() {
    val sequences = listOf(
      Sequence("2b", listOf("1a")),
      Sequence("1a", emptyList()),
      Sequence("3c", listOf("2b")),
      Sequence("91z", emptyList()),
      Sequence("92z", listOf("91z")),
      Sequence("NO_CHAIN", emptyList())
    )

    val sequenceChains = sequences.filter { it.previousSequence.isNotEmpty() }
    val baseOfChainList = sequences.filter { base ->
      base.previousSequence.isEmpty() && sequenceChains.any { it.previousSequence.contains(base.id) }
    }

    val listOfChains: MutableList<MutableList<Sequence>> = mutableListOf()

    baseOfChainList.forEach {
      val individualList: MutableList<Sequence> = mutableListOf()
      individualList.add(it)
      individualList.addAll(recursiveAddSequence(it.id, sequenceChains))
      listOfChains.add(individualList)
    }

    println(listOfChains)
  }


  fun recursiveAddSequence(id: String, sequenceChains: List<Sequence>): List<Sequence> {
    val individualChain: MutableList<Sequence> = mutableListOf()
    sequenceChains.forEach {
      if (it.previousSequence.contains(id)) {
        individualChain.add(it)
        individualChain.addAll(recursiveAddSequence(it.id, sequenceChains))
      }
    }
    return individualChain
  }
```

Comment: *I'm inheriting somebody else poor design* - so what exactly *can* you change about this? Can you change the initial data structure? Or should you just change the algorithm?

Comment: Also, do you ignore chains of one element on purpose?

Comment: Just change algorithm.. yes ignore chains of one element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can solve this with the following code:

```kotlin
val (heads, notHeads) = sequences.partition { it.previousSequence.isEmpty() }
val sequencesByPrevious = notHeads.associateBy { it.previousSequence.first() }
val result = heads.map { head ->
    generateSequence(head) { sequencesByPrevious[it.id] }.toList()
}
```

First, we prepare a map of items by their previous item. Then for each item that is the head (does not have a previous item), we iterate over next elements one step at a time.

`generateSequence()` is a tricky part. This function creates a lazy and unbound sequence of items (note it is a different "sequence" than in your example). It acquires subsequent items by applying the provided lambda to the previous item and it does this over and over again until it gets null. This single line is an equivalent of this loop:

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf<Sequence>()
var curr: Sequence? = head
while (curr != null) {
    list += curr
    curr = sequencesByPrevious[curr.id]
}
```

If we are not interested in elements that don't belong to any chain (they don't reference and are not referenced by any other item), then we can simply filter them out (thanks @Joffrey):

```kotlin
result.filter { it.size > 1 }
```

As a bonus: if I'm correct, your solution has at least quadratic time complexity. Above solution is linear.

Comment: Great solution! I think you also need to filter out single-element sequences, because the OP apparently excludes them. But that's trivial once you have this

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks, it seems like it was intentional in OP's example.

Comment: I dont really understand how  generateSequence works.. but the bottom line is that it works. I'm reading up and playing with generateSequence

Comment: OK.. I think I get it now. Very clever. sequencesByPrevious is a map. Then generate runs over each record until it finishes

Comment: @JohnHarrison I added a better explanation to my answer, because `generateSequence()` is really tricky (but simply awesome at the same time!).

Comment: @broot excellent explanation thanks for showing it as conventional code!